# Any light version of JQuery UI's autocomplete box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I need an autocomplete selection box for a page, something like [JQuery's autocomplete box](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

However, adding JQuery and JQuery UI just for that functionality seems like overkill. Is there any lighter alternatives?

Comment: I'm sure you already know this, but I wanted to point out that you can do a custom download of jQuery UI with only the Core + Autocomplete -- avoiding downloading all of jQuery UI.

Comment: Also, if you're at the point of needing autocomplete, you might want to get jQuery anyway-- sounds like your page has enough features that jQuery is going to get really useful really fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code project example builds an auto-complete from pure javascript with no dependencies on jQuery.  [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/485062/AJAX-AutoComplete-control-with-JavaScript-and-PHP)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout DevBridge Ajax Autocomplete: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

We have recently extracted the JS from django-autocomplete-light, giving [jquery-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/jquery-autocomplete-light) which you might like.